# How to repeat in R

Tags: r

I am a newbie in R, now I have a vector H(0.6,0.045,3), I want to create a matrix A, the number of rows of this matrix can be determined by myself, each row is the value of this vector:0.6,0.045,3. like this:

```
A (0.6,0.045,3,
   0.6,0.045,3,
   0.6,0.045,3,
   0.6,0.045,3,
  ............)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can specify number of rows and columns in `matrix` function.

```
vec <- c(0.6,0.045,3)
nr <- 4
matrix(vec, nrow = nr, ncol = length(vec), byrow = TRUE)

#      [,1]  [,2] [,3]
#[1,]  0.6 0.045    3
#[2,]  0.6 0.045    3
#[3,]  0.6 0.045    3
#[4,]  0.6 0.045    3
```

---

Another option is to use `replicate` :

```
t(replicate(nr, vec))
```